# How to change color of HTML tags on TinyMCE source code view

Tags: jquery, css, tinymce

I am using TinyMCS for my editor, i want to change color of HTML tags on TinyMCE source code view. Is there any plugin for this goal or any CSS or jQuery solution.

I used following code for create my editor:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: ".tinymce",theme: "modern",height: 300,
    content_css : '/fonts/Nassim.css, /css/public.css',
    language: "fa_IR",
    plugins: [
         "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
         "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
         "table contextmenu directionality emoticons paste textcolor responsivefilemanager code"
   ],
   toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | styleselect",
   toolbar2: "| responsivefilemanager | link unlink anchor | image media | forecolor backcolor  | print preview code ",
   image_advtab: true ,

   external_filemanager_path:"/assets/plugins/filemanager/",
   filemanager_title:"Responsive Filemanager" ,
   external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "/assets/plugins/tinymce/plugins/filemanager/plugin.min.js"}
 });
```

Comment: do you mean something like a code highlighter or the general font color in the surce code view?

Comment: code highlighter @Marat